# Laravel Homested file upload performance issue

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I am having a wierd problem with Laravel Homestead. After following all the steps(with success) in Laravel website to configure Homestead and setting up a small project I'm facing the following problem:

- When uploading an image with intervention\image package it takes forever, and doesn't matter if it is a small or a big image

Already tried a different config using Vaprobash with Nginx too and the upload is super fast.
Is anyone out there facing the same problem or have some solution for me? (Going crazy here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the upload folder is a shared folder on your host, then you may want to enable `nfs` if you haven't already. You can do that by changing the lines in `scripts/homestead.rb` about shared folder to this (note the `type: "nfs"' has been added):

```
# Register All Of The Configured Shared Folders
settings["folders"].each do |folder|
  config.vm.synced_folder folder["map"], folder["to"], type: "nfs"
end
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html.

Comment: Just to make sure: you did reprovision you Vagrant box, right?